# Does ol3-cesium accept DEM files?

Tags: openlayers, 3d, 3d-map, cesium

I'm using OpenLayers 3.6.0. I want to use [`ol3-cesium`](http://openlayers.org/ol3-cesium/). `Ol3-cesium` use [`cesium`](http://cesiumjs.org/) for glob visualization. I have a question:

**In ol3-cesium, Can I see Ups and downs of land? In other words Does it accept DEM files?**

Comment: This question was correctly answered [here on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30879918/836708).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use DEM.
By default you will use cesiums default STK [world terrain provider](https://cesiumjs.org/data-and-assets/terrain/stk-world-terrain.html)

There is an example how to enable terrain provider for cesium at [ol3-cesium website](http://openlayers.org/ol3-cesium/)

```
var ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({map: map}); // map is the ol.Map instance
var scene = ol3d.getCesiumScene();
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
  url: '//cesiumjs.org/stk-terrain/tilesets/world/tiles'
});
scene.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;
ol3d.setEnabled(true);
```

If you need to server your own terrain data check [geoserver plugin](https://github.com/kaktus40/Cesium-GeoserverTerrainProvider)